# Small Game Lag On Really Fast Moving Player

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

**Problem**

So I've made this mobile game and it has a player which travels really fast. As the player travels really fast, the camera also needs to follow along. The problem is that sometimes there is a small lag as you play. Is there a better way to write my script for following fast moving objects?

**Camera Follow Script**

```
private void LateUpdate () {

    Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (player.transform.position.x + offset.x,
                            transform.position.y,
                            player.transform.position.z + offset.z);

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime * 40);

}
```

**Game download links, if you want to test for yourself**

[Android Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SiddharthN.TheLongRush&hl=en)

[iOS Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jumpol/id1331808162?ls=1&mt=8)

Comment: Have you watched the framerate during the time you experience this slowness? Is the hardware you are playing on capable of playing this game in its highest quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector3.Lerp is called every frame. In your example, the value of Lerp is **transform.position** when t = 0 and **pos** when t = 1. i.e it interpolates from point A to B between t = [0 to 1]. The lag (or chugging) could be because of that. If the distance of A and B is 10 and t = 0.5 then the camera moves by 50%, i.e 5. If in the next frame, the distance is 50 and t = 0.5 the camera still moves 50%, but the distance is 25. Hope it is clear.

Why don't you simply set **transform.position = player.transform.position + offset**?